# Qual è il significato di "inerme" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Mi occupai io della casa, cucinai, mi dedicai a Gennaro. Forse perché era già grandicello, un po’ aggressivo, capriccioso, trovai il bambino privo dell’**inerme** seduzione che sprigionava Mirko, l’altro figlio di Nino.

Malgrado abbia cercato il significato di "inerme" in alcuni dizionari (ho visto che può significare "disarmato", "indifeso"), non riesco a capire il suo senso in questo brano. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Forse Mirko seduce senza fare nulla per sedurre.

Comment: Non sono del tutto sicuro che sia una domanda sulla lingua italiana: una volta appurato qual è il senso letterale di “inerme” (e cioè appunto “disarmato”, “indifeso”), l'interpretazione di un suo specifico uso figurato in una specifica opera letteraria spetta al lettore.

Comment: Può darsi, @DaG, ma il termine "inerme" mi risultava talmente strano (era totalmente sconosciuto per me) che pur cercandolo nel dizionario non ero capace di immaginare nessuna interpretazione dell'espressione "inerme seduzione". Adesso, tanto l'interpretazione di egreg come quella di Denis Nardin mi sembrano plausibili. Forse una buona risposta dovrebbe includere tutte e due queste possibili interpretazioni.

Answer (score 1):

La mia interpretazione della frase è che il fatto stesso che Mirko fosse inerme (cioè incapace completamente di difendersi) sia la cosa che produce la seduzione, mentre Gennaro, che ha un fare più aggressivo e deciso, non suscita gli stessi sentimenti nella narratrice.

Comment: La tua interpretazione mi sembra del tutto plausibile. Mirko è un bambino molto piccolo, che piange nella braccia della madre. Quando la narratrice lo prende per cercare di acquietarlo, si sente subito atratta dal bambino. Ma quello detto da @egreg mi sembra anche una buona interpretazione: essendo tanto piccolo, Mirko non ha sviluppato "armi" per cercar di sedurre, quindi "seduce senza fare nulla per sedurre". Secondo me, una buona risposta dovrebbe includere tutte e due queste possibili interpretazioni. Ti andrebbe di aggiungere la spiegazione di egreg al tuo post?